# Delphi OnCreate: strange behaviour while creating a form

Tags: forms, delphi, oncreate

I am still using Delphi 10.3.3

I have my own form class

```
TMyForm = class( tForm )
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
end;

{ ... }

constructor TMyForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  { code block A }
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  { code block B }
end;
```

I have about 200 forms - but some behave differently than the other and I have no clue why.

In general the `code block A` will be executed, then the code within the `OnCreate` of my forms and then `code block B`.

But for some reason some forms execute the code in following order: `code block A`, `code block B` and then `OnCreate`.

I know that this is very little information. But I have no idea where could I look for the reason of the different behaviour or what other information should I provide.

Comment: It seems to me as [`OldCreateOrder`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.OldCreateOrder) issue. When a form has `OldCreateOrder` set to `False` (default) then `OnCreate` event occurs after the form constructor.

Comment: Thx Peter - that was the reason.